# Is 'concomitant' intentional?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, adjectives

Is the word 'concomitant' utilized only when intention attends the usage? The word 'attendant' means the same in many cases but doesn't seem to carry the sense of intentional concurrency. Should these two words be treated as we treat 'look' and 'see', 'listen' and 'hear'? (I was thinking about these examples... 'look' is intentioned while 'see' is not necessarily intentioned.)

(information from some later comments made by the original poster):

- In fact, I think I have it all backwards. I was focused less on definition and more on application - but after another click, 'Attend' seems to suggest more intention than 'concomitant' ([Merriam-Webster: "attend"](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attend)).
- There is even a suggestion that no intention attends the usage ([Merriam-Webster: "concomitant"](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concomitant)).

Comment: Could you please cite a definition from a professionally-compiled dictionary (in other words not Wiktionary, Wikipedia, or The Urban Dictionary)  that says something about "intention" 
regarding the word *concomitant*?

Comment: @Clare There are words which tend to be used only when the overall valence of the sentence is of a certain type, even if they don't actually impart such a meaning themselves. I think this is what is being asked here - does it occur predominantly in sentences where intention is present.

Comment: It depends whether you mean that it is in accordance with intention. The answer would seem to be no - it refers to subordinate matters, and can be used for side effects that are antithetical to the intended outcome. "This tendency holds *despite the concomitant* mistrust of politicians and governments ..." - [The AIDS Notebooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=BDdgzA2A-t0C&pg=PA7&dq=%22despite+the+concomitant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir08Wt-obXAhXJ6iYKHb8OB6sQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=%22despite%20the%20concomitant%22&f=false)

Comment: genref, as @Clare implies. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concomitant) has: << naturally accompanying or associated.
"she loved travel, with all its concomitant worries" >>. Nobody goes looking for worry. ODO licenses the no-intention association.

Comment: @Phil Sweet If you're going to second-guess what questions might mean when they already have a different readily understandable meaning, you're going to compromise the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How should I interpret 'attends the usage'? I don't think that even slightly implies that I should expect to find the thing listed as part of the dictionary definition. But I did wonder about raising this matter on meta. I guess it's time to do that.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear? Cite some definitions (which may or may not mention intention) and also some uses in real world sentences (which may or may not involve intention). Also, please make the analogy with look/see more explicit (which two words...concomitant and attendant? which is supposed to go with which?)

Comment: You make the assumption as to what OP means in your second 'comment'. Clare's request for a dictionary reference is totally valid; the example I quote from ODO answers the question as OP phrases it. Even if you unjustifiably put the words '[D]oes it occur **predominantly** in sentences where intention is present?' into OP's mouth, the counter-example given by ODO, who monitor usage levels and avoid rare usages, gives the answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the excellent feedback. You're right, this may not be the right forum and I did not research it enough before asking my question. I'm new here and your discussion about my question is also a valuable instruction to me to ask more effectively.

Comment: I was impressed by the root of 'concomitant' as it strongly suggests to me an intention is at play:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit

@Clare, good point :) There is even a suggestion that no intention attends the usage:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concomitant

Comment: In fact, @Phil Sweet, I think I have it all backwards. Not only did you interpret my approach accurately - I was focused less on definition and more on application - but after another click, 'Attend' seems to suggest more intention than 'concomitant':
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attend !

Comment: I'm not clear on what it means for intention to attend the usage.  Is there some special meaning of intention in classifying types of usage . . . or something?

Comment: @Xanne, "as we treat 'look' and 'see', 'listen' and 'hear'?" I am was thinking about these examples... 'look' is intentioned while 'see' is not necessarily intentioned.

Comment: @Tamir but *look* and *see* are verbs while you're asking about adjectives.

Comment: @clare, yes. I just thought the question applied equally to both, as well as adverbs, actually.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'intention'? How is 'look' intentioned (is that a verb?)... How does 'look' have intention, but not 'see'? Also, can you give example parallel sentences with 'concomitant' and the other one where it might be more apparent what you mean?

Comment: It appears to me that looking is a verb used when we want to see something while seeing could happen without the intention to see. Like listening and hearing. I can't listen to something without wanting to do so. But i could certainly hear the car crash into the lamppost without intending to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Checking OLD, Cambridge and Merriam-Webster for meaning, we glean the following:

> Naturally accompanying or associated. [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concomitant)
>
> Something that happens with something else and is connected with it. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concomitant)
>
> Accompanying especially in a subordinate or incidental way.
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concomitant).

Note nowhere in any of the above defintions is the word intended used (or any similar connotation).

Concomitant was Merriam Webster's word of the day on 03/07/2007, this special privilege afforded the word its own short podcast, which can be found a short way down M-W reference. The podcast relates the Latin roots of the word:

> ...a descendant of Latin concomitari ("to accompany") and
> ultimately of "comes," the Latin word for companion...

The podcast continues to describe two related words:

> The two associated words, the verb concomitate, meaning "to
> accompany," and another adjective, concomitaneous, meaning "of a
> concomitant nature," didn't survive to accompany "concomitant" into
> the 18th century.

It is noticeable then that the Latin roots of the word are also absent of any *intentional* quality.

Steven J. Jensen, in [Good and Evil Actions: A Journey Through Saint Thomas Aquinas](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dc6expKGVKwC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=concomitant%20intention&source=bl&ots=_XHYvJhPad&sig=NahhRWi4owio-6NDCiAxgaEtibU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKtP6vxYrXAhVDVhoKHYE8COsQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=concomitant%20intention&f=false) makes use of the compound adjective *concomitant-intentional* when describing three scopes of object regarding intention:

> We will call these views, respectively, concomitant-intention,
> end-intention, and means-intention.

This would make no sense at all if there was some inherent quality of intention in the word concomitant.

Having considered the above we can state with confidence then that there is no intentional quality to the word concomitant.

Concomitant refers to the quality of 'accompanying' (OLD, Merriam-Webster) or 'connect[ing]' (Cambridge). It has nothing at all to do with intention.

Comment: +1 even more than I knew by instinct